# How to change guid of .net dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, guid

I am currently created c# dll and use it in c++ application.
In C# dll, there is one exporting class with unique guid.
When I create instance using CoCreateInstance function, only one instance is created in memory.
I want to create two or more instances of c#, so I think if I can change guid of c# dll, then c++ application can create two ore more instances using CoCreateInstance.

How can I change guid of deployed dll programmatically?
or How can I create two instances in c# dll?

Comment: A Guid for a DLL is to uniquely identify the library, I don't think that changing the guide will help you create many instances. Check if you have the class as Singleton or other options

Comment: In c# project, there are some global variables(static variable, etc). so if I can load twice a c# dll in memory, every thing is ok.

Comment: Why do you want to load two copies of a DLL?

Comment: You can create two instances simply by calling CoCreateInstance twice.

Comment: @goldstar: Wouldn't work. Below CoCreateInstance, there's a LoadLibrary call. It merely increments the reference count when you try to load a DLL for the second time. (This is to prevent a single FreeLibrary call from unloading the DLL)

Answer (score 0):

You're using COM, which means you should be playing by COM rules. Putting object state in a global variable is wrong, and will cause the kind of problems you observe.

Now some global state might be acceptable, e.g. a directory where to store logfiles. So the practice of global variables isn't banned outright. C# doesn't try to second-guess you. If you used global variables, C# assumes that you used them wisely and not for object state. But since you do need the state per object, you must change those variables to be members, not global.s